# How to find course module that is not overlap?

Tags: neo4j

I am new to `neo4j` and trying out

```
Q1 - what are the modules both Computer Science and Applied IT have in common
Q2 - what are the modules that are available in Computer Science but not Applied IT
Q3 - what are the modules that are available in Applied IT but not Computer Science
```

Let's say if:

1. Computer Science has Module 1
2. Computer Science has Module 2
3. Computer Science has Module 3
4. Applied IT has Module 1
5. Applied IT has module 3

Based on Match, I am able to find Q1 based on similar match, but having problem with `Q2` and `Q3`. How do I find the nodes that's do not match? In this case Applied IT has no module 2 when compare to Computer Science.

Basically I want to find module that do not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Q2: What are the modules that are available in Computer Science but not Applied IT

```
MATCH (compSci:Course { name:"Computer Science" })-[:hasModule]->(m)
MATCH (applied:Course { name: "Applied IT" })
WHERE NOT ((applied)-[:hasModule]->(m))
RETURN m
```

Q3: What are the modules that are available in Applied IT but not Computer Science

```
MATCH (applied:Course { name: "Applied IT" })-[:hasModule]->(m)
MATCH  (compSci:Course { name:"Computer Science" })
WHERE NOT ((compSci)-[:hasModule]->(m))
RETURN m
```

Sample graph: http://console.neo4j.org/r/nmit8h

Comment: Also see Luanne's GraphGist for Organisational Learning: http://gist.neo4j.org/?8021754